# What does 'a hairline crack where the grip meets the graphite shaft on my 3-wood' mean in this English joke?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, terminology

> Guys,
>
> I have suspected for some time now that my wife has been cheating on me. I think deep down I just did not want to know the truth, but last night she
>   went out again and I decided to finally check on her.
>
> Around midnight, I hid in the garage behind my golf clubs so I could get a
>   good view of the whole street when she arrived home from a night out with
>   'the girls. '
>
> When she got out of the car she was buttoning up her blouse, which  was
>   open, and she took her panties out of her purse and slipped them on.
>
> It was at that moment, crouching behind my golf clubs, that I noticed *a
>   hairline crack where the grip meets the graphite shaft on my 3-wood*.
>
> Is this something I can fix myself or should I take it back to the pro-shop
>   where I bought it?

What does that sentence mean in this English [joke](http://www.jokes2go.com/13/3/j3.html)?

Edit: It surprises me that this question would get many comments and upvotes, thanks folks. I feel compelled to write an explanation. The reason I think this question isn't off-topic basic on:

> I never seen a real and clear golf club in my life, so when I look up those words, it quite stuck me there, because I can't form an image of what it specifically look like in details on my mind; In situation to understand something that's not exist to you before with a Dictionary seem very hard, because you has to form a concept of it from nearly nowhere. For example, if you are a Mandarin learner, when you encounter words like '礼金', '奶金', you might have a hard time to understand that even if you look them up in dictionary, because, as far as I know, there isn't similar concepts of them in English, that's where you might need to ask someone who understand Mandarin for an explanation, and understand the background and culture of those words that usually doesn't defined on a dictionary.

Comment: Have you looked up the words *hairline, grip, graphite, shaft, 3-wood*? If so, what is it you still don't you understand?

Comment: As StoneyB notes, the meaning here is literal. It's not a punch line. The joke is that the narrator is suddenly more concerned about the golf club than about the marriage.

Comment: @StoneyB i look up each word, but when they combine together as a sentence, i can't get what it is telling. especially 'the grip meets the graphite shaft on my 3-wood.' part.

Comment: His golf club, a three-wood, has a graphite shaft. The grip is at the top of the shaft, and at the point where the grip meets (adjoins) the shaft there is a hairline crack. The joke is that he's more interested in his golf club than his wife's infidelity.

Comment: @StoneyB thanks. why grip 'meet' the shaft? isn't it a part of it at the top itself? (sorry, i am using my mother language's search tool to translate those words)

Comment: @choster  OK, it's just that part of sentence i don't quite understand.

Comment: @user239460 "Where the grip meets the shaft" refers to the border between the grip and the non-grip part of the shaft.  If you think the "grip" is part of the "shaft", well, context alone should clear up the confusion regardless of what language it's in.  The comment about how these are "thinly-veiled allusions" doesn't make any sense to me and probably does not represent the interpretation of most native English-speakers.

Comment: @Darren Ringer thanks. i never seen stuff like that before, so i am having hard time to imagine it. after reading Andrew's answer, i finally realize what it's about.

Comment: @choster - And it could well be that his obsession with golf is the root cause of his marital problems. (I don't think the joke would ring as funny if he suddenly noticed a crack in his garage floor, for example, or a small dent in the car he was crouching behind.)

Comment: Please learn from this question not "why the joke is funny" but the lesson: _"Always consult your English dictionary to learn the meanings of words"_. A corollary lesson: _"Many words, like 'club', have multiple definitions: read them all."_

Comment: I must say I'm a little surprised that nobody is even mentioning the double-entendre plastered in the punch line. The joke is a switcheroo, but the double entendre (like grip, shaft, wood) is also kind of a red herring. If you really want to look too deep, you could say that discovering his wife's infidelity put a crack in his shaft.

Comment: @TBear Yes. Yes. Yes. Oh God, yesss. That's the main reason why I visited the post, I wanted to see how someone would handle  "wood" and "shaft" And TIL that a golf club also has a "head":)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A "hairline crack" is a very thin crack that threatens the integrity of some object.
[image: Hairline crack in a tabletop]

The "grip" is where you hold the golf club.
[image: golf club grip]

The "graphite shaft" is the long part of the club, which these days is frequently made from graphite not wood:

[image: graphite golf club shafts]

A 3-wood is a particular kind of golf club used for hitting the ball long distances:

[image: head of a 3-wood]

The man says the crack is "*between* the shaft and the grip".  I'm not a golfer but I assume this means the grip might come loose from the rest of the club, or at the very least, affect how well the club hits the ball:
[image: parts of a golf club]

The joke is that the man is more concerned about his golf clubs than his marriage.  It uses a comedic device known as a "reversal" or ["switcheroo"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switcheroo), in which the reader expects the story to go one direction, but it actually leads to an unexpected conclusion.

I also slightly edited your question to include the initial "Guys" from the original.  The joke is more humorous in the context of someone telling his story to some kind of newspaper or online ["advice column"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advice_column).

Comment: thank you. very elaborated answer, it's easier to understand for person like me who never seen a stuff like that. so it mean that there is a hairline crack in the graphite shaft? am i right?

Comment: @user239460  It actually says "a hairline crack **between** the shaft and the grip".  Let me edit my answer to include another image.

Comment: thanks, what does the word 'club' mean in 'the grip might come loose from the rest of the club'?  i thought you said it was a 'shaft'?

Comment: The *club* is the whole thing together -- the grip, the shaft, and the head.

Comment: sorry, i thought it is some kind of place where people drink or sing, like a pub. so if i am right, there is a hairline somewhere in the club, is it?

Comment: To rephrase it: one of my golf clubs is starting to break.

Comment: @user239460 "club" has multiple meanings. While it does mean what you suggested, in this case it refers to the golf club, the thing used to hit the ball in golf. (Confusingly, "golf club" can also refer to an organisation that one can sign up to in order to play golf on a specific set of courses).

Comment: @user239460 Ha, yes, "club" has many meanings, including a group of people who gather from a common interest, or a place where such people gather.  It's also a large wooden stick which can be used as a weapon.

Comment: You really buried the lede there, down in the penultimate paragraph after 5 pictures. You might consider moving that paragraph (or one like it) to the top of this answer.

Comment: @T.E.D. the original joke *is* the lede.  OP's question was about the specific meaning of the English words, not why the question is funny.  Anyway I deconstruct it so much that it can't possibly be funny any more by the time I explain the joke.

Comment: +1 I like the structure of this answer because it parallels the structure of the joke in that the first part of the answer concentrates on the meanings of the individual words and phrases and then at the end it pivots to the actual meaning of the sentence in question in the context of the whole joke.

Comment: @Muzer  thanks. that's indeed confusing, especially the "golf club" is even more confusing, don't know why it not create new words to refer it in English.

Comment: As a footnote, in the phrase _hairline crack where the grip meets the shaft_, I think it's ambiguous about whether the grip is cracked or the shaft is cracked. (That said, where the crack is located doesn't matter insofar as the joke is concerned. We thought we were being asked a relationship question; instead, it's a question about golf club repair. Switcheroo successful.)

Comment: @Andrew Whenever I tell a joke, I always explain it as awkwardly as possible to make sure no one enjoys it anymore. It works wonders.

Comment: not to mention there's a lot of evidence supporting her infidelity lol blouse open, panties off and hidden?  It's a very silly joke, love it!

Comment: @corsiKa my wife HATES it when I do this. It make a joke 1000xs funnier to me though.

Comment: *made from graphite not wood*.  Cheaper / older golf clubs have metal (steel) shafts, not wood.  The *head* of a simple/cheap 3-wood would be made of wood, but not the shaft.

Comment: @user239460 Both meanings have a [common origin](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=club). This happens in other languages besides English.

Comment: @corsiKa, I don't always explain a joke...but when I do, I explain it really awkwardly so no one ever asks me to explain a joke again, because it's so unfunny by that time.  Get it?  Because it's like the meme, that plays off of that guy in the Dos Equis ad?  And the joke is that I'm explaining the joke, which is a joke about explaining jokes.  But because it's irritating to overanalyze humor then no one is likely to ask me to explain my jokes anymore, even if they don't understand them.  Instead, they'll just laugh (or not) and I won't have to explain!

Answer (score -2):

I see at least two interpretations.  Andrew's answer does a great job of parsing the joke for individual definitions, so I won't reiterate that.

The first interpretation is more apparent and has already been covered: The husband prioritizes his possessions so greatly that it distracts him from an event so significant as a cheating spouse.  His hobby is more important than his wife's loyalty and happiness--which strongly implies that he's not a very good husband, and he's likely always golfing.  Further, his focus is poorly directed.  The signs of a cheating spouse are generally easy to spot for someone invested in the relationship (extended outings, less affectionate, etc), but in his dark garage he was able to spot a hairline crack on his club--which isn't easy to see even in daylight.

It's suddenly very understandable that his wife is cheating.  At the outset of the joke, she began as the villain, but there's now sympathy for her, stuck with a husband who is so dedicated to something aside the marriage that he neglects her completely, driving (bad golf pun) her into the arms of another man.

There's another interpretation--albeit a darker one.

The husband was angry at his wife for cheating and hit her with the golf club (maybe even killed her with it).  In his rage he swung the club so hard that he cracked the handle but he's trying to convince those who suspect him of the crime that he's innocent, and the golf club had nothing to do with her assault/murder/disappearance.  He wants to persuade the listener that the telltale crack was already there before his wife got home and doesn't implicate him.

Of course modern forensics (in this case common sense as well) would render his alibi a very weak one at best.  And of course there's the horrific juxtaposition of humor and committing a brutal murder.

But hey, come on... it's a joke.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing to indicate he attacked his wife, he was crouching behind his clubs observing his wife when he noticed the crack.

Comment: Many punchlines are open to interpretation and inference, double entendre and paraprosdokian.  FWIW I've never attacked anyone with a 3-wood, just saw an alternate inference and figured it's worth a mention. I don't know if that's an alternate, subversive intent of this specific joke--nor did I say I'd even find that funny--but I've seen jokes like it.  I'll comment again if I think of one, but none come to mind ATM.

Comment: thanks for your sharing of story of this joke, it really is amazing that it means so much in it.